# Upload an image to server using chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, file-upload, google-chrome-extension

I am doing a chrome extension capable of getting from a webpage an image, and after I got it, I'm trying to upload it to an intranet server automatically without user iteration.

I am doing this right now.

This is on Content_script.js

```
...
x = $(frame1).contents().find("#image");
chrome.extension.sendRequest(x[0].src);
...
```

This is on background.js

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(links) {
      chrome.downloads.download( { url: links , 
      conflictAction: "overwrite", 
      filename: "get_image.jpg" }, 
      function(DescargaId) { 
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("doc", Blob, "~/Downloads/get_image.jpg");
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.open("POST", "http://192.168.0.30/app_get_pictures/upload_img.php");
            request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
            request.send(formData);
} );
```

This on upload_img.php

```
 ...
 $uploaddir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/app_get_pictures/images/';
 $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['doc']['name']);
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES['doc']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile);
 ...
```

With this, I already download the image successfully to the local machine, but can't upload the image to the server.

It is possible to do this, or even if I can upload the image to the server directly without download it first to the local machine.

***Note: I don't have any tag form on a popup page in the extension solution, and I don't have a popup page neither, because as I already said, I don't need any iteration from the user.***

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try converting the image to a Blob directly, examples should be easily googlable, you'll need `"<all_urls>"` in manifest.json's `"permissions"`.

Comment: In most cases,wouldn't it be more efficient to send the image URL to the server and let the server fetch the image itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/934239/xan I resolved this problem using his advise, here is the resulting working code.

```
    ...
    // With this I can download or get content image into var blob
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var kima = $(frame1).contents().find("#image");
    xhr.open('GET',kima[0].src,true);
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';

    xhr.onload = function(e) {
      if (this.status == 200) {
        var blob = new Blob([this.response], {type: 'image/png'});
        send_image(blob);
      }
    };

    xhr.send();
    ....

    // After the image is loaded into var blob, it can be send
    // to the server side
    function send_image(x){
         var formData = new FormData();
         formData.append("doc", x);

         var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
         request.open("POST", "http://192.168.0.30/app_get_image/upload_img.php");
         request.send(formData);
     }
```

**All this code into the content_script of the chrome extension.** Also the code of the background using API `download` isn't needed anymore.
Hope this could works for anybody else.

***Thanks again.***

Answer (score 0):

Besides the fact that the callback of `downloads.download` does NOT indicate that the file is already downloaded (only that the download is queued)..

```
formData.append("doc", Blob, "~/Downloads/get_image.jpg");
```

What do you think this code does? [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append), for reference.

The second parameter is supposed to hold the data of the file; the third parameter is just the file name for the purposes of naming anonymous data (e.g. in a `Blob`)

Instead, you pass the `Blob` object itself; not an *instance* of `Blob` with the data.

In fact, **with this architecture, you won't be able to upload the file**, since *at no point* does `chrome.downloads` API give you access to the file's contents, and you can't just access a file on a disk by filename (which is what I think you thought this code would do).

To actually access the data, you need to request it yourself with XHR (or Fetch API if you want to be "modern"). Then, you get the response object which you can [request to be a Blob](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/#toc-response). Then, you can both upload the blob *and* invoke `chrome.downloads` together with [`createObjectURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) to "download" it from your extension's memory.

Comment: thanks for your advise, but also I'm stock in this thing. If I'm not wrong with your explanation, API doesn't give me access to the file contents, then the only way is to using XHR to upload the file,, but where can I put the XHR, in the content script or in the backgroud script?, Thanks again.

Comment: _"But where can I put the XHR, in the content script or in the backgroud script"_ From the XHR perspective - shouldn't matter, as content and background scripts have the same level of access. But to call `downloads` API it must not be a content script.

Comment: Seems to be impossible. Because I already download to local machine the image from the web page, with `downloads` API in the background script, but can't upload it to my server.

Comment: You can't access downloaded files. At all. What I'm proposing is a two-step process: download into memory first (with XHR), and save that copy from the memory to two places (upload and `downloads.download`).

Comment: Thanks again with your quick response. Ok, I 'll try first download with XHR and then with that in memory upload it to my server. I will try without using `downloads` API.